# Change display number from 2 to 1

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, amd-graphics, amdgpu

I am using some extensions that are using Main.layoutManager to identify the monitor number, but my primary monitor is monitor number 2, this makes everything work on my secondary monitor rather than my primary one.

How can I change the numbering of my primary monitor form number 2 to 1 so that I can use both monitors at the same time without the need to disconnect my secondary monitor ?

I am using an AMD R9 270x graphics card.

**Things i tried that didn't work**

1- Remove the monitors.xml file so that I plug the primary monitor only then and reboot then connect the secondary monitor

```
rm ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

2- I tried xrandr to assign my primary display again but still no change

```
xrandr --output "DisplayPort-0" --primary
```

**Update**: I upgraded to ubuntu 23.04 and at the same day my cmos died during a power-outage and that reset the bios (it's a 10 yo pc).
Now they are ordered to the way I wanted them to be, so luckily it got fixed on it's own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually set display numbers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1229016/manually-set-display-numbers)